# Why is state of array not updating in Next.js using 'useEffect' and 'useState'?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, next.js13

I have this code in next js using 'use client' and no matter what I tried task list is not being updated, it's an empty array also tried to log it by using useEffect as a dependency but nothing.

```js
    const [taskList, setTaskList] = useState<any[]>([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTaskList([
            {
                assigned_to: "id",
                collectionId: "cid",
                collectionName: "tasks",
                completed: false,
                created: "2023-05-28 19:16:09.740Z",
                id: "tid",
                reward: 73,
                story: "<p>hello test 3</p>",
                title: "test3",
                updated: "2023-05-28 19:20:07.549Z"
            },
            {
                assigned_to: "id",
                collectionId: "cid",
                collectionName: "tasks",
                completed: false,
                created: "2023-05-28 19:16:09.740Z",
                id: "tid",
                reward: 33,
                story: "<p>jdhgfjsdf</p>",
                title: "gajhfg",
                updated: "2023-05-29 11:27:50.158Z"
            }
        ])
    }, [])
```

here is how taskList is being used

```js
            <div className="grid xl:grid-cols-3 p-20">
                {taskList.map(async (task) => {
                    return (
                        <Task
                            title={task.title}
                            reward={task?.reward}
                            assignedTo={''}
                            id={task?.id}
                        />
                    )
                })}
            </div>
```

I know how to react state updates I can't get the updated value after re-render but this is not the issue, I can't even render the taskList by mapping it and can't get the data updated.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you've posted. You're most likely either confused about how React state works, or you have Javascript error when trying to render the newest `taskList`. Please post more code showing the actual issue.

Comment: React render functions are synchronous. Remove `async`. It also seems likely that you're ignoring Javascript errors. Get in the habit of reading errors, don't ignore them.

Comment: i am not confused how react state works and i clearly stated that on the post

Comment: after all this wasted MINUTES! i completely forgot i had the async function, thank you!

Comment: also there are no errors that have appeared, neither inside editor nor the console

Comment: Making a function `async` makes it return a `Promise` which is an object, and React can't render objects as children, and errors ([like this](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-euclid-59msly?file=/src/App.js)). Your code should be raising an error, if you're not seeing one, it's worth taking the time to figure out why not.

Answer (score 0):

```js
                {taskList.map(async (task) => {
                    return (
                        <Task
                            title={task.title}
                            reward={task?.reward}
                            assignedTo={''}
                            id={task?.id}
                        />
                    )
                })}
```

Update: removed the async from map function and it's working now!